# Oracle SQL Developer - Script Output with Query result displayed

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Impossible to get back the Query result for PL/SQL scripts. It was working fine earlier in the afternoon but something might have gone wrong and now results have vanished from screen. What should I do?
Thank you!

[image: The query result tab is missing]

The dummy query is just an example even if I should also get DUMMY as column header and X as a unique record in a "Query result" tab. In fact my script is such as below and works but gives no viewable data because the "Query Result" has gone. Before to reinstall Oracle SQL Dev I am wondering if on trick exists to fix this point for which I have found no valuable fix so far.

```
declare
    v_tab varchar( 30 ):= 'MD_ALL_DETAIL_';
    v_date1 varchar( 30 ):= '0827D';
    v_date2 varchar( 30 ):= '0830';
    v_tab1 varchar( 30 );
    v_tab2 varchar( 30 );
    v_sql varchar( 2000 );
begin
    v_tab1 := v_tab || v_date1;
    v_tab2 := v_tab || v_date2;
    v_sql := '
with tab as(    
    select ' || v_date1 || ' flag, md1.*
    from ' || v_tab1 || ' md1
    union all
    select ' || v_date2 || ' flag, md2.*
    from ' || v_tab2 || ' md2
), tab2 as (    
select *    
from(   
    select tab.flag, tab.cat_mk_code, tab.cat_mk_iden, tab.b_entity_code, tab.b_entity_iden, tab.cat_be_code, tab.cat_be_iden, tab.bucket_code, tab.
    bucket_iden, tab.m_entity_code, tab.application_code, tab.indicator_code, tab.indicator_iden, tab.measure_value, tab.user_code, tab.lock_flag,
    tab.alter_date, tab.table_name
    from tab
)pivot( 
    sum( measure_value )
    for flag
    in( ' || v_date1 || ' as MEASURE_0, ' || v_date2 || ' as MEASURE_1 )
) ) 
select * from tab2 where MEASURE_0<>MEASURE_1';
    execute immediate v_sql;
end;'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code (at the screenshot) doesn't do *anything*, so message you got ("PL/SQL procedure successfully completed") is all you can expect.

Run e.g.

```
select * from dual;
```

and SQL Developer will automatically open the *missing* "Query Result" tab.

---

If you want to "display" the result of a dynamic SQL, you'll have to select it **into** something. A simple example:

[image]

See? I'm selecting from `DUAL` (as your initial query does) `INTO` a local variable. The result is displayed within the **Script output** tab.

Your "new" code uses a more complex query, possibly returning more than a single column/row so you can't select into a scalar variable. I presume you'll have to create a `TYPE`, declare a local variable (a collection, probably) and then do *something* with the result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Littlefoot. I have amended the post as it was missing a bit context.

Comment: I have also seen that a simple select statement bring back the "Query result" but the "Query result" is still not fed by data coming from a script (the one above for my example)

Comment: To resume: I made the mistake of closing the result tab of a query, running the same query does not open a new tab so I do not have the result of the query. Even after restarting the application.

Comment: I added some more info into the answer; have a look.

Comment: The weird thing is that it was working fine in the afternoon, I had just to click on the "Query result" tab to see the result of the immediate query with multi-column and rows. I will try to reinstall the Oracle Sql server application. Thank you Sir ;)

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS01317

If dynamic_sql_statement is a SELECT statement, and you omit both into_clause and bulk_collect_into_clause, then execute_immediate_statement never executes.
For example, this statement never increments the sequence:

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT S.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL'

Comment: Hello @Dynamo432- I have updated the post for more clarity